# shouldInvalidateLayout disable scrolling of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, header

I recently got an application created by another developer with `UICollectionView` and custom header. I want to implement a header bouncing like [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvTLGIJaRGk), but when I override `shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect)` scrolling in `UICollectionView` disabling at all. I can't put any code here, because of NDA. But maybe somebody know which parameter of `UICollectionView` can block scrolling when override this method or how I can find a path to resolve this problem?